# using this “ ∀ · · · x, · · · .” No computer scientists are unemployed

Tags: logic

i am not sure how this statement can be done as i am familiar solving question which had integers similar to the statment for example Every real number is is negative, zero, or positive. Then i would get is for all x in real number, x is less than zero, x = 0  and x > 0.

Comment: I have read what you wrote five times and I still have no idea what you are asking!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez so am I :-(

Comment: How familiar with sets are you?

Answer (score 10):

Let $C(x)$ denote "x is a computer scientist," and let $U(x)$ denote "x is unemployed."

Then we have: $$\forall x(C(x) \rightarrow \lnot U(x))\tag{1}$$

---

ADDED: Note that if you are confused about why speaking of "*no* computer scientist x such that U(x)" translates to a statement about *all* computer scientists, note that we can start with a more literal translation, and work our way to $(1)$.

"(There are) no computer scientists (that) are unemployed" more literally translates to

"There does not exist an x such that x is a computer scientist AND x is unemployed." $$\lnot \exists x(C(x) \land U(x))\tag{2}$$

Recall that we can "push the negation inwards; $$\lnot \exists x P(x)\equiv \forall x \lnot P(x)$$

In our case, pushing negation inwards gives us $$\begin{align} \lnot \exists x(C(x) \land U(x)) &\equiv \forall x\Big(\lnot(C(x) \land U(x))\Big) \\ \\ 
&\equiv \forall x \Big(\lnot C(x) \lor \lnot U(x)\Big)\tag{DeMorgan's}\\ \\ 
&\equiv \forall x \Big(C(x) \rightarrow \lnot U(x)\Big)\tag{1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to explain translation of sentences into logic symbols (by no means am I a teacher), but I think this would translate to
$$
\forall x \in \{ x \mid x \text{ is a computer scientist} \} \lnot \mathrm{Unemployed}(x)
$$
where $\mathrm{Unemployed}(x)$ represents the boolean of whether or not $x$ is employed.